# Prevent executing jpa @Query in JUnit

Tags: spring-boot, junit, h2

I have a Spring Boot project (version 2.3.1.RELEASE) and I am trying to write JUnit tests not using databases (all mocked).

For this I have configured a junit environment H2 as the database

```
spring.datasource.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;TRACE_LEVEL_FIlE=4
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
```

And with this quite regular Repository

```
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Long> {

@Query("SELECT A FROM Account A WHERE "
            + "A.state='PENDING' AND "
            + "P.origin='WS' AND "
            + "UPPER(P.type)='R'")
    public List<Account> pending();
}
```

My Test Controller starts with

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = LoadBranchesController.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { Constant.ROOT_PACKAGE })
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-junit.properties")
class LoadBranchesControllerTest {
```

My problem comes when I run ControllerTests in junit tests. Upon bootstrap, it complains:

```
2020-10-20 20:37:38 WARN  -  WARN - org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper -  SQL Error: 42102, SQLState: 42S02
2020-10-20 20:37:38 ERROR - ERROR - org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper -  Table "AP_ACCOUNTS" not found; SQL statement:
```

It happens because he's trying to check this query. But H2 is empty (the way I want it).

Is there a way to disable the query execution of JpaRepositories upon bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution had two legs, applied in every Test class:

1. In ComponentScan, the repositories must be excluded

```
    @ComponentScan(Constant.ROOT_PACKAGE + ".helper")
```

So, all Beans with @Query, must be outside all the scanned Components

2. The components autowiring repositories at anytime, must be mocked, even if they are not used

```
    @MockBean
    private AccountRepository accountRepositoryMock;
```